# Placement of a relative pronoun

Tags: grammar, british-english, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns

Please consider the following sentence:

> Ada Lovelace is the first computer programmer in the world who wrote the code for analytical engine.

Is the placement of the relative pronoun "who" correct?
Or should it be like this:

> Ada Lovelace who is the first computer programmer in the world, wrote the code for analytical engine.

Should the relative pronoun come after the word that refers to it?

Comment: A. Lovelace **is thought** to be… Use the past tense  when describing achievements or jobs of people who are now dead, e.g. **she was a computer programmer**

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem isn't just the placing of a pronoun but that the sentences are unsalvageable. You could consider rewording as

> Ada Lovelace wrote the code for [Babbage's] analytical engine, making her the first computer programmer in the world.

Answer (score 0):

I think this question will be closed but the comments have been disabled.

So, here is the question:

"Ada Lovelace is the first computer programmer in the world who wrote the code for analytical engine.

Is the placement of the relative pronoun "who" correct? Or should it be like this:

Ada Lovelace who is the first computer programmer in the world, wrote the code for analytical engine."

There are several errors.

Ada Lovelace, the first computer programmer in the world, wrote the code for the analytical engine.

I have no idea what an analytical engine is, but it needs a determiner. And you don't need *who* at all. You can use an apposition.

Comment: It was Charles Babbage's design for a prototype 'computer' in the 1830s.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, sure, I did not look it up.

Answer (score 0):

> Ada Lovelace, who wrote the code for Babbage's analytical engine, was the  world's first computer programmer.

Answer (score 0):

> [1] *Ada Lovelace was the first computer programmer in the world* [*who wrote*
> *the code for analytical engine*]
>
> [2] *Ada Lovelace, who was the first computer programmer in the world, wrote*
> *the code for analytical engine*.

The relative pronoun "who" *does* come after the word/phrase that it refers to.

In [1] "who" has the adjacent nominal "first computer programmer in the world" as antecedent.

In [2] "who" has the adjacent noun phrase "Ada Lovelace" as antecedent.

Since "first computer programmer in the world" refers to Ada Lovelace, there is little difference in meaning between the two other than one of emphasis.

Note the punctuation.